# Verifying that the Laplacian is the infinitesimal generator of a semigroup.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

Let
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}u(t,x)&=\Delta u(t,x),\quad t>0,\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\
u(0,x)&=f(x)
\end{align}

where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (Heat's equation)

The heat kernel is the function $p_t(x-y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi}\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\,d\xi$. This kernel satisfies that $\partial_t p_t=\Delta p_t$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}p_t*u=u$ in the $L^2$-norm (I just checked).

Now I would like to verify, from these properties, that
$\Delta$ is the infinitesimal generator of the semigroup $T(t)$ given by $(T(t)u)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}P_t(x-y)u(y)\,dy,\quad u\in L^2$.

By definition, I must verify that $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{T(t)u-u}{t}=Au$ for all $u\in D(A)=\left\{u\in L^2: \Delta u\in L^2\right\}$

**Question 1.** This limit is in $L^2$? or not?

**Question 2.** How proves that $\Delta$ is the infinitesimal generator of the semigroup $T(t)$?

**Actualization**. In question 1, the answer is affirmative. See [In what sense is the limit in the definition of infinitesimal generator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727836/in-what-sense-is-the-limit-in-the-definition-of-infinitesimal-generator/4727839#4727839)

Question 2. I still don't know how to proves it. Only i have this:
\begin{align}
(\partial_t-\Delta) (S(t)u)(x)&=(\partial_t-\Delta)\int p_t(x-y)u(y)\,dy\\
&=\int (\partial_t-\Delta)p_t(x-y)u(y)\,dy\\
&=0
\end{align}
but I don't know how to justify the step baoj the intergal sign

Actualization 2.

\begin{align}
\partial_t (S(t)u)&=\partial_t (p_t*u)\\
&=(\partial_t p_t)*u\\
&=(\Delta p_t*u)\\
&=p_t*(\Delta u)\\
&\to \Delta u
\end{align}

Comment: Did you accidentally hit the "post/ask-a-question" twice? You should remove one of your two identical questions. :)

Comment: Oh. now is ready.