# In what sense is the limit in the definition of infinitesimal generator?

Tags: banach-spaces, semigroups

[image]

**Question**. $Ax=\left.\frac{d^+}{dt}T(t)x\right|_{t=0}$ means that

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0^+} \left\| Ax-\frac{T(t)x-x}{t}\right\|_{X}=0?
\end{align}
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Comment: Could you share the textbook you are using?

Comment: @Akira This is Pazy's book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5561-1.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unsurprisingly, your interpretation is correct.

One potential issue is, indeed, in what sense that limit exists or is taken. If the adjective is "uniform", then, yes, it should be in the uniform-operator-norm sense. But, in fact, there are many situations in which this is not the thing to do... and the limit should be in the (weaker...) "strong operator topology".